# mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table

Tags: mysql

`mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table`

happens, when I do a

mysqldump -u root -p database >dumpfile.sql

I increased max_allowed_packet to the max value already (1073741824) to no avail.

How come that one cannot dump a database with mysqls on board means?
Cause may be a longblob in a data row/column which may be maximum size of 4 GB (4294967295 bytes).

Could it be the network transport being used? Would there be another transport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump error: Got packet bigger than max\_allowed\_packet'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815445/mysqldump-error-got-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use below command
mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=512M -u root -p database > dumpfile.sql

This will solve your issue