# I am getting an error while using 'mysql' on Google cloud shell : ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-shell

Basically, I am trying to import a csv file into a table in Google Cloud SQL database.. The query, I used to create a table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Mobike(
 orderid INT(30), 
 bikeid INT(30), 
 userid INT(30), 
 start_time DATETIME, 
 start_location_x FLOAT(30,30), 
 start_location_y FLOAT(30,30),               
 end_time DATETIME, 
 end_location_x FLOAT(30,30), 
 end_location_y FLOAT(30,30), 
 track TEXT(65000));
```

Like Table, CSV file also contains the same columns having same data Types. Kindly, help me how I can solve this problem especially when I am doing it on Google cloud shell?? And how can I remove this error??

Comment: Could you specify what is your shell command like?

Comment: @EvandroSilva It was a simple command of "Select * from Mobike".. I just wanted to view the data, which i imported from csv file to my table named 'Mobike'..But, it's giving the above mentioned error..

Comment: Please, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922910/mysqldump-error-2020-got-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes-when-du

Comment: Hey Evandro.. I don't know about that 'dumpfile.sql' and where to run your suggested command (mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=512M -u root -p database > dumpfile.sql) on shell... Kindly, give me some explanation that if i am using 'MYSQL' on cloud shell, how can i run this query there?? If u can tell me some steps to do this, it would be appreciable.. :)

Comment: [The `max_allowed_packet` default value is 4MB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), maybe your query is returning more than that? Try connecting setting this flag to a higher value, as [described here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html), the GCE also has a way of altering the `mysql` flags, [check this link for more info](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags), hope it helps.

Comment: I got your point and i have altered the mysql flag using your given link.. I have defined the maximum value to 'max_allowed_packet' in the flag.. But, still it's giving the same error, when i run my query(Select * from Table) on cloud shell..